# Pick specific folder in S3 that is in Glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

I am tying to pick a specific folder in S3 that is in Glacier and output the results in a csv format.  I am able to pull the objects at a bucket level, but not a folder level.  Example/yxz/.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: What does "pull" and "pick" mean? Generally S3 does not have folders, but keys and prefixes. Do you want to "..." all objects under a given prefix?

Comment: Yes, Scan by a specific prefix that is in Glacier and output the result in a CSV format

Comment: Just working if anyone has insight as to how this can be done?